# How to UNNest multiple arrays in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this json that is stored in a BigQuery table in 3 fields token, questions, answers

token:STRING, questions:STRING, answers:STRING

Questions and answers are `STRING` because they are dynamic fields.

**token** field has single value.

**questions** field has `dictionary` object with "fields" being `list` object and has 3 questions.

**answers** field is a `list` object with answers to the 3 questions and `id` will be used for matching a question to an answer. Below is the JSON download from bigquery

```
token          questions                                      answers
18e6d8e445     {"fields": [{"id": "L39FyvUohKDV", "properties": {}, "ref": "d8834652-3acf-4541-8354-1e3dcd716667", "title": "What did you think about the changes?", "type": "short_text"}, {"id": "krs82KgxHwGb", "properties": {}, "ref": "5b6e6796-635b-4595-9404-e81617d4540b", "title": "How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?", "type": "opinion_scale"}, {"id": "lBzHtCuzHFM4", "properties": {}, "ref": "b76be913-19b9-4b8a-b2ac-3fb645a65a5c", "title": "Your email address", "type": "email"}], "id": "SdzXVn", "title": "Google Shopping 5/4/18"}       [{"field": {"id": "L39FyvUohKDV", "type": "short_text"}, "text": "t", "type": "text"}, {"field": {"id": "krs82KgxHwGb", "type": "opinion_scale"}, "number": 10, "type": "number"}, {"email": "t@t.com", "field": {"id": "lBzHtCuzHFM4", "type": "email"}, "type": "email"}]
949b2c57e3     {"fields": [{"id": "krs82KgxHwGb", "properties": {}, "ref": "5b6e6796-635b-4595-9404-e81617d4540b", "title": "How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?", "type": "opinion_scale"}, {"id": "lBzHtCuzHFM4", "properties": {}, "ref": "b76be913-19b9-4b8a-b2ac-3fb645a65a5c", "title": "Your email address", "type": "email"}, {"id": "L39FyvUohKDV", "properties": {}, "ref": "d8834652-3acf-4541-8354-1e3dcd716667", "title": "What did you think about the changes?", "type": "short_text"}], "id": "SdzXVn", "title": "Google Shopping 5/4/18"}       [{"field": {"id": "krs82KgxHwGb", "type": "opinion_scale"}, "number": 10, "type": "number"}, {"email": "someone@mail.com", "field": {"id": "lBzHtCuzHFM4", "type": "email"}, "type": "email"}, {"field": {"id": "L39FyvUohKDV", "type": "short_text"}, "text": "they were awesome", "type": "text"}]             
146c49cdd6     {"fields": [{"id": "CxhfK22a3XWE", "properties": {}, "ref": "d8834652-3acf-4541-8354-1e3dcd716667", "title": "What did you think about the changes?", "type": "short_text"}, {"id": "oUZxPRaKjmFr", "properties": {}, "ref": "5b6e6796-635b-4595-9404-e81617d4540b", "title": "How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?", "type": "opinion_scale"}, {"id": "zUIP73oXpLD6", "properties": {}, "ref": "b76be913-19b9-4b8a-b2ac-3fb645a65a5c", "title": "Your email address", "type": "email"}], "id": "kaiAsx", "title": "a - b"}                        [{"field": {"id": "CxhfK22a3XWE", "type": "short_text"}, "text": "nice", "type": "text"}, {"field": {"id": "oUZxPRaKjmFr", "type": "opinion_scale"}, "number": 2, "type": "number"}, {"email": "foo@bar.com", "field": {"id": "zUIP73oXpLD6", "type": "email"}, "type": "email"}]
```

@mikhail-berlyant provided this query below which gets me pretty close to what I am expecting. The only problem I am having is that I am unable to get the answer.

```
SELECT distinct token, id, title AS question,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(CONCAT('{',a,'}'), '$.type') answer_type
--REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(b, r'"type":".+?"\s*,\s*".+?":(.+)'), '"', '') answer
FROM `v1-dev-main.typeform.responses`,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(JSON_EXTRACT(definition, '$.fields'), r'"title":"(.+?)"')) title WITH OFFSET pos1,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(JSON_EXTRACT(definition, '$.fields'), r'"id":"(.+?)"')) id WITH OFFSET pos2,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(answers, r'"field": {(.+?)}')) a WITH OFFSET pos3
--UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(answers, r'{(.+?),\s*"field":{.+?}')) b WITH OFFSET pos4
WHERE pos1 = pos2 
--AND pos3 = pos4 
AND id = JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(CONCAT('{',a,'}'), '$.id')
```

Here is the result of above query

```
token                       id             question       answer_type
146c43c81cd5780839d3cdd6    zUIP73oXpLD6    Your email address  email
146c493c1cd5780839d3cdd6    oUZxPRaKjmFr    How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?   opinion_scale
146c493c05d5780839d3cdd6    CxhfK22a3XWE    What did you think about the changes?   short_text
18e6d8e33df44a1aa451b445    lBzHtCuzHFM4    Your email address  email
18e6d8e33df44a1aa451b445    L39FyvUohKDV    What did you think about the changes?   short_text
18e6d0fa014bfa1aa451b445    krs82KgxHwGb    How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?   opinion_scale
a63b20df691c9a949b2c57e3    krs82KgxHwGb    How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?   opinion_scale
a63b20df691c9a949b2c57e3    lBzHtCuzHFM4    Your email address  email
a63b258ce0339a949b2c57e3    L39FyvUohKDV    What did you think about the changes?   short_text
```

Now, I am just missing the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL and makes some assumption about your data in terms of how those json strings are formatted - so it most will likely require some tuning for regexp's. But it works with below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 12345 token, 
'''{"fields": [
    {"id":"1","title":"Question 1?"},
    {"id":"2","title":"Questions 2?"},
    {"id":"3","title":"Question 3?"}
  ]}''' questions,
'''[  
  {"type":"text", "text":"answer 1", "field":{"id":"1", "type":"short_text"}},
  {"type":"number", "number":42, "field":{"id":"2", "type":"opinion_scale"}},
  {"type":"email", "email":"an_account@example.com", "field":{"id":"3", "type":"email"}}
  ]''' answers 
)
SELECT token, id, title AS question,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(CONCAT('{',a,'}'), '$.type') answer_type,
  REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(b, r'"type":".+?"\s*,\s*".+?":(.+)'), '"', '') answer
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(JSON_EXTRACT(questions, '$.fields'), r'"title":"(.+?)"')) title WITH OFFSET pos1,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(JSON_EXTRACT(questions, '$.fields'), r'"id":"(.+?)"')) id WITH OFFSET pos2,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(answers, r'"field":{(.+?)}')) a WITH OFFSET pos3,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(answers, r'{(.+?),\s*"field":{.+?}')) b WITH OFFSET pos4
WHERE pos1 = pos2 
AND pos3 = pos4 
AND id = JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(CONCAT('{',a,'}'), '$.id')
```

with results as

```sql
Row token   id  question        answer_type     answer   
1   12345   1   Question 1?     short_text      answer 1     
2   12345   2   Questions 2?    opinion_scale   42   
3   12345   3   Question 3?     email           an_account@example.com
```

> Update based on below comments

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "12345" token, '{"fields": [{"id":"1","title":"Question 1?"},{"id":"2","title":"Questions 2?"},{"id":"3","title":"Question 3?"}]}' questions,'[  {"type":"text", "text":"answer 1", "field":{"id":"1", "type":"short_text"}},{"type":"number", "number":42, "field":{"id":"2", "type":"opinion_scale"}},{"type":"email", "email":"an_account@example.com", "field":{"id":"3", "type":"email"}}]' answers UNION ALL
  SELECT "18e6d8e33df440fa014bfa1aa451b445", '{"fields": [{"id": "L39FyvUohKDV", "properties": {}, "ref": "d8834652-3acf-4541-8354-1e3dcd716667", "title": "What did you think about the changes?", "type": "short_text"}, {"id": "krs82KgxHwGb", "properties": {}, "ref": "5b6e6796-635b-4595-9404-e81617d4540b", "title": "How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?", "type": "opinion_scale"}, {"id": "lBzHtCuzHFM4", "properties": {}, "ref": "b76be913-19b9-4b8a-b2ac-3fb645a65a5c", "title": "Your email address", "type": "email"}], "id": "SdzXVn", "title": "Google Shopping 5/4/18"}', '[{"field": {"id": "L39FyvUohKDV", "type": "short_text"}, "text": "t", "type": "text"}, {"field": {"id": "krs82KgxHwGb", "type": "opinion_scale"}, "number": 10, "type": "number"}, {"email": "t@t.com", "field": {"id": "lBzHtCuzHFM4", "type": "email"}, "type": "email"}]"' UNION ALL
  SELECT "a63b258ce03360df691c9a949b2c57e3", '{"fields": [{"id": "krs82KgxHwGb", "properties": {}, "ref": "5b6e6796-635b-4595-9404-e81617d4540b", "title": "How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?", "type": "opinion_scale"}, {"id": "lBzHtCuzHFM4", "properties": {}, "ref": "b76be913-19b9-4b8a-b2ac-3fb645a65a5c", "title": "Your email address", "type": "email"}, {"id": "L39FyvUohKDV", "properties": {}, "ref": "d8834652-3acf-4541-8354-1e3dcd716667", "title": "What did you think about the changes?", "type": "short_text"}], "id": "SdzXVn", "title": "Google Shopping 5/4/18"}', '[{"field": {"id": "krs82KgxHwGb", "type": "opinion_scale"}, "number": 10, "type": "number"}, {"email": "someone@mail.com", "field": {"id": "lBzHtCuzHFM4", "type": "email"}, "type": "email"}, {"field": {"id": "L39FyvUohKDV", "type": "short_text"}, "text": "they were awesome", "type": "text"}]"' UNION ALL
  SELECT "146c493c051a0a481cd5780839d3cdd6", '{"fields": [{"id": "CxhfK22a3XWE", "properties": {}, "ref": "d8834652-3acf-4541-8354-1e3dcd716667", "title": "What did you think about the changes?", "type": "short_text"}, {"id": "oUZxPRaKjmFr", "properties": {}, "ref": "5b6e6796-635b-4595-9404-e81617d4540b", "title": "How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?", "type": "opinion_scale"}, {"id": "zUIP73oXpLD6", "properties": {}, "ref": "b76be913-19b9-4b8a-b2ac-3fb645a65a5c", "title": "Your email address", "type": "email"}], "id": "kaiAsx", "title": "a - b"}', '[{"field": {"id": "CxhfK22a3XWE", "type": "short_text"}, "text": "nice", "type": "text"}, {"field": {"id": "oUZxPRaKjmFr", "type": "opinion_scale"}, "number": 2, "type": "number"}, {"email": "foo@bar.com", "field": {"id": "zUIP73oXpLD6", "type": "email"}, "type": "email"}]"'
)
SELECT token, id, title AS question,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(CONCAT('{',a,'}'), '$.type') answer_type,
  COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(b, '$.text'),JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(b, '$.number'),JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(b, '$.email')) AS answer
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(JSON_EXTRACT(questions, '$.fields'), r'"title":\s*"(.+?)"')) title WITH OFFSET pos1,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(JSON_EXTRACT(questions, '$.fields'), r'"id":\s*"(.+?)"')) id WITH OFFSET pos2,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(answers, r'"field":\s*{(.+?)}')) a WITH OFFSET pos3,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(REGEXP_REPLACE(answers, r'"field":\s*{.+?}', '"field": ""'), r'{.+?}')) b WITH OFFSET pos4
WHERE pos1 = pos2 
AND pos3 = pos4 
AND id = JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(CONCAT('{',a,'}'), '$.id')
```

Output is

```sql
Row token                               id              question                                                answer_type     answer   
1   12345                               1               Question 1?                                             short_text      answer 1     
2   12345                               2               Questions 2?                                            opinion_scale   42   
3   12345                               3               Question 3?                                             email           an_account@example.com   
4   18e6d8e33df440fa014bfa1aa451b445    L39FyvUohKDV    What did you think about the changes?                   short_text      t    
5   18e6d8e33df440fa014bfa1aa451b445    krs82KgxHwGb    How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?   opinion_scale   10   
6   18e6d8e33df440fa014bfa1aa451b445    lBzHtCuzHFM4    Your email address                                      email           t@t.com  
7   a63b258ce03360df691c9a949b2c57e3    krs82KgxHwGb    How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?   opinion_scale   10   
8   a63b258ce03360df691c9a949b2c57e3    lBzHtCuzHFM4    Your email address                                      email           someone@mail.com     
9   a63b258ce03360df691c9a949b2c57e3    L39FyvUohKDV    What did you think about the changes?                   short_text      they were awesome    
10  146c493c051a0a481cd5780839d3cdd6    CxhfK22a3XWE    What did you think about the changes?                   short_text      nice     
11  146c493c051a0a481cd5780839d3cdd6    oUZxPRaKjmFr    How useful is this feature turning out to be for you?   opinion_scale   2    
12  146c493c051a0a481cd5780839d3cdd6    zUIP73oXpLD6    Your email address                                      email           foo@bar.com
```

Comment: This is helpful. I understand it works for the sample json I added. But I am having some issues with the real data. It's working till answer_type. I am not able to get answer. And, I believe, it's because the order of key value in answers list is not same. Is there a way to work around that? Thanks.

Comment: vote up if it is helpful. meantime, to continue on this question  - you need to provide better examples of your input data - as I mentioned in my answer - ` it most will likely require some tuning for regexp's. ... it works with below dummy data`

Comment: I did vote up right away when I saw the response for the first time. I will provide more data soon.

Comment: thank you. yes - the better you examples and explanations on data design you have in place you will provide  - the more chances for working solution :o)

Comment: i saw your update. it is still not helpful enough. you said you have three fields - all of string type. can  you just simply show them separately as a strings as you see them in result panel of BQ UI when you do something like `select * from table limit 3` - don't copy what you see in json mode of result - rather show what you see in table mode of result!

Comment: Updated. See if this helps

Comment: makes more sense now. one more Q - inside answers field - your order of keys is random? it looks like it. is it?

Comment: Yes order is random

Comment: so if it is - there should be extra logic that will allow to select needed key. for example even though order is random - the number of keys are always three: field, type and third one that depends on type. if this would be a case this would allow to select that one key. so do you have something like this in mind? otherwise - i don't see the way to extract exact answer - rather than extract the whole element with respective id

Comment: What you said is correct, "for example even though order is random - the number of keys are always three: field, type and third one that depends on type."   the answer value is either in key "text" or "number". Will that help?

Comment: did you see my update? I thought it addressed your recent comments! please confirm

Comment: Just saw it. I was only looking at comments. Will get back in few minutes.

Comment: Sure. Glad I was able to help. That's why we are there for. :o) One important aspect to learn is to how properly/optimally ask the question such that you get answer faster, better quality and most importantly attract more users to answer - not only those like me who can read between the lines :o) See you in next posts

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about length of your arrays it's possible to ARRAY_CONCAT them first and perform UNNEST with concatenated version. It worked for me.